# Ruby, get difference between GMT of timezone

Tags: ruby

I'm going to get difference between GMT (for example: `+09:00`) in Ruby, using TZInfo gem. I'm reading documentation and I can't find the solution. I tried:

```
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Shanghai')
puts tz.strftime('%:z')
```

But it returns +00:00, that's not correct, why? It's looks like it still using London time.

Comment: I don't think there is any place that has the difference `+90:00`.

Comment: Oops, missclick. Sorry

Comment: you can try this `Time.now.in_time_zone('Asia/Shanghai')` this will return `Thu, 11 Feb 2016 20:23:50 CST +08:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, but as someone pointed out, you can't just use the location, you need to check for daylight savings etc.

```
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('Asia/Shanghai')
puts sprintf("%02d:%02d", *tz.current_period.offset.utc_offset.divmod(3600))
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I Found utc_offset in `tz.current_period.offset.utc_offset`

Comment: deleting this answer since it's wrong, @siper make an answer

Answer (score 0):

A time zone by itself does not have the notion of a time difference because the time difference may change during the period within the year (some time zones have summer time). You need to assign particular date time in order to get a meaningful time difference.